# JS / GraphQL View - BigCommerce Master SKU

Tags: javascript, graphql, handlebars.js, bigcommerce, graphql-js

What is the best way to output the master SKU for BigCommerce on to the front end view using handle bars.

I have used GraphQL but the response is too slow to be used as really it needs to be something that can be output on render. Any ideas would be appreciated.

GraphQL Code

```
        <script type="text/javascript">
            fetch('/graphql', {
                method: 'POST',
                headers: {
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                    'Authorization': 'Bearer {{ settings.storefront_api.token }}'
                },
                body: JSON.stringify({query: `
                    query {
                        site {
                            product(entityId: {{ product.id }}) {
                                sku
                            }
                        }
                    }
                `})
            }).then(function(response) {
                return response.json();
            }).then(function(response) {
                console.log(response.data.site.product.sku);
            });
        </script>
```

Comment: HB? as ajax? for updates? ... those days???  use headless (BE/API as source of data), frontend more separated - use modern FE ... react or prerendered gatsby

Answer (score 2):

If you are on a product page:

`{{product.sku}}`

If you are on a category page:

```
{{#each products}}
   {{sku}
{{/each}}
```

You can debug the context available to each page to understand the data available within Stencil CLI:

https://developer.bigcommerce.com/theme-objects#viewing-a-pages-context